# Delphi - what event is triggered inside TDBGrid on dataset.enablecontrols

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

I need to know what happens in a TDBGrid when the dataset is calling [enablecontrols](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/Data.DB.TDataSet.EnableControls). I understood that dataset is notifying the datasource, but I don't know what is called on the dbgrid component before the [OnDrawCell](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/Vcl.DBGrids.TDBGrid.OnDrawColumnCell) event.

from db.pas the dataset is calling

```
  if (FDisableState <> dsInactive) and (FState <> dsInactive) then
    DataEvent(FEnableEvent, 0);
```

How the datasource is notifying the dbgrid about how many columns it needs to display?

Comment: TDataLink > TGridDataLink

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DataSources are linked to data-aware controls via data links (`TDataLink`). Every data control creates a `DataLink` in order to respond to and to signal the attached `DataSource`.

The DataLink of a `DBGrid` is of type `TGridDataLink` which is created in `TCustomDBGrid.CreateDataLink`.

This is the call stack after `TDataSet.EnableControls`:

- `TDataSet.EnableControls` calls `TDataSet.DataEvent`,
- `TDataSet.DataEvent` calls `FDataSources[I]).DataEvent` for all attached data sources,
- `TDataSource.DataEvent` calls `TDataSource.NotifyDataLinks`, which calls `TDataSource.NotifyLinkTypes`,
- `TDataSource.NotifyLinkTypes` calls `FDataLinks[I]).DataEvent` for all attached data links,
- `TDataLink.DataEvent` calls `TGridDataLink.DataSetChanged` or `TGridDataLink.LayoutChanged`, depending on what happened before `EnableControls` was called. An edit to a record is a dataset change; an addition of a field (column in the grid) is a layout change (among others),
- `TGridDataLink` calls `FGrid.DataChanged` or `FGrid.LayoutChanged`,
- `TCustomDBGrid.LayoutChanged` eventually calls `TCustomDBGrid.BeginLayout`,
- `TCustomDBGrid.BeginLayout` delegates the update of the columns (count, titles, etc.) to the `Columns` property and calls `Columns.BeginUpdate`.

`OnDrawCell` takes place sometime in the future, when all layout changes are made.